# Sql Server 2014 Return Specific Result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with making query in Sql Server 2014.
I have following table

```
ID           Part
SP470PR 
SP470PR     181607
SP470PR     1030
```

I need the results to be displayed as follows:

```
ID           Part
SP470PR     181607
SP470PR     1030    
181607      SP470PR
181607      1030    
1030        181607
1030        SP470PR
```

Can anybody help me with this query?
I try to use Lead function but I cant get the results that I want?

Thank you

Comment: What is the datatype of `Part`?

Comment: The datatype is nvarchar

Comment: Your sample data is not appropriate to have your expected result.. what do you mean by that sample result?

Comment: I want to rotate data.. For example, After Second and third row are displayed as it is, I want Second data from Part to become ID, then third row etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using CROSS JOIN:-

```
Select * from table
where part is not null
union all
Select distinct a.part as ID,b.ID as part from
(select part from table) a 
cross join
(select id from table) b
where part is not null
union all
Select a.part as ID,b.part from
(select part from table where part is not null) a
cross join
(select part from table where part is not null) b
where a.part<>b.part
```

Comment: @user3782230 did you try this query?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very samll sample of data, so I'm not sure I got it right, but with the help of union an a join I got this:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE
(
    ID nvarchar(10),
    Part nvarchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('SP470PR', NULL), 
('SP470PR', '181607'), 
('SP470PR', '1030')
```

The query:

```
SELECT ID, Part
FROM @T 
WHERE Part IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT Part, ID
FROM @T 
WHERE Part IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT t1.Part, t2.Part
FROM @T t1
INNER JOIN @T t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
WHERE t1.Part <> t2.Part
ORDER BY ID DESC, PART DESC
```

Result:

```
ID      Part
SP470PR 181607
SP470PR 1030
181607  SP470PR
181607  1030
1030    SP470PR
1030    181607
```

Comment: Here is my whole table (@India.Rocket), but there is NOT always several fields with same ID...  http://partsshop.mk/Test_script.rar

Comment: I will not download it. You should create a minimal sample data that will cover all the conditions you need and edit your question accordingly. Also, please post the sample data as I've done in my answer - as DDL+DML so that we could check our answers before posting them.